# Django: tests.py as a module

Tags: python, django, unit-testing, testing, python-module

#### Background:

I'm using Django 1.8.

And I'm beginning to test on it.

When I use the `models.py` or `views.py`, I usually remove them, and create a module folder with the same name to replace.

In this way, I can split the models and views to different code files and make them easy to edit.

---

#### Question:

But when I tried to change the `tests.py` to a module folder, I found that the test cases in the `__init__.py` cannot run.

What's wrong? If I want to do so, is there any way?

Please help, thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/testing/overview/#running-tests):

> Test discovery is based on the unittest module’s built-in test
>   discovery. By default, this will discover tests in any file named
>   “test*.py” under the current working directory.

so I guess tests in `__init__.py` won't be discovered automatically.

Comment: Well, you are right, and I finally found that if I create files like `test*.py` in my tests folder, they will be triggered.

Answer (score 1):

Though your question is already answered, I'd like to share my test-setup.

Let's assume I have an application `foo` with the following structure

```
foo
    admin.py
    apps.py
    fixtures
        testdata_01.json
    forms
        bar.py
        __init__.py
    __init__.py
    models
        bar.py
        __init__.py
    static
        foo
            base.css
            foo.js
    templates
        foo
            home.html
            ...
     tests
         forms
             bar.py
             __init__.py
          views
             bar.py
             __init__.py
          __init__.py
          test_run.py
    urls.py
    views
        bar.py
        __init__.py
```

As you can see, I have some `Bar` models in my app. All corresponding elements are in their own modules, i.e. `forms.bar` and `views.bar`.

Now look at the `tests` module: As already stated, the Django test-runner will automatically run all tests in `test*.py`, in my setup this is `test.test_run.py`.

**test_run.py**

```
from .forms.bar import *
from .views.bar import *
```

As you can see, the real tests are in equally named files, so I can see with one glance, which part of the application will be tested, i.e. `tests.forms.bar` includes all tests related with forms for the `Bar` class.

**tests/forms/bar.py**

```
from ...tests import FooTest

class FooBarFormTests(FooTest):
    """Contains all tests for BarForm"""

    def test_constructor(self):
        self.assertTrue(True)

    def test_clean(self):
        self.assertTrue(False)
```

Did you note the base class `FooTest`? This class is located in `tests/__init__.py`.

**tests/__init__.py**

```
from django.test import TestCase

class FooTest(TestCase):
    """Base class for all app specific tests"""
    fixtures = ['testdata_01.json']
```

As you can see all common tasks, like assigning specific test-data is done in this base class.